# Implementing ETL in PHP with automation

Tags: php, automation, etl

I have a requirement were I have to get the data from several files with different formats and totally unorganized and having randomly named fields.. convert that data into one single format and store in the corresponding fields of table in database.. So I know the concept of ETL but I have no idea what logic should I use because this is something totally new for me and never worked on something like this before..
Could anybody guide me how can I compare the random and raw data with the database table fields?

For example: File 1 has 3 columns: Cust name | Number | Email

File 2 has same fields but named differently like: Customer name | no. | email-id

So I just need to know what are the ways I could get this done or if there is any better option than ETL to this requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this as part of data cleansing.

1. If you don't have many source tables you can try with a manual mapping table. Source (n) -> Target (1) and then some addtional magic to load the data.
2. If you have more source tables you can try to guess (edit distance of names) the correct target table name. Probably with addtional check of the containing data.
3. What you can do as well is to only check the containing data

   - @ included -> email
   - usally 2 words where 1 is a surname -> customer name
   - only numbers, no dots -> Customer number